# CSS 3D object not rotating around true axis

Tags: css, sass

As you can see below, the numbers and tickmarks are not rotating flush to the axis of the red circle to which they are, ostensibly, attached. Why is that?

It looks like there is some sort of invisible padding between where the ticks start to rotate from, and where the actual center of the circle is, causing them to spin about while also rotating.

```js
var x = true;

$(document).on("click", function() {
 if(x) $("#pomodoro").css("transform", "rotateX(85deg) rotateZ(540deg)");
 else $("#pomodoro").css("transform", "rotateX(85deg) rotateZ(180deg)");
 
 x=!x;
}); // provided for quick viewing of the issue
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono");
html, body {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background-color: #bbddff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mark-face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
          transform-origin: bottom;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.time-mark {
  height: 250px;
  left: calc(50% - 1ex);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50vh - 266px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 19.2px;
}

#pomodoro {
  background-color: #ff9999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(85deg) rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: rotateX(85deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 6s linear 0s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 6s linear 0s;
  transition: transform 6s linear 0s;
  transition: transform 6s linear 0s, -webkit-transform 6s linear 0s;
  width: 500px;
}

#pomodoro-container {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 500px;
}

#tick1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
          transform: rotate(12deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
          transform: rotate(18deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
          transform: rotate(24deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
          transform: rotate(36deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(42deg);
          transform: rotate(42deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick8 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(48deg);
          transform: rotate(48deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick9 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
          transform: rotate(54deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick11 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(66deg);
          transform: rotate(66deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
          transform: rotate(72deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick13 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(78deg);
          transform: rotate(78deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick14 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(84deg);
          transform: rotate(84deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick15 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick16 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(96deg);
          transform: rotate(96deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick17 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(102deg);
          transform: rotate(102deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick18 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
          transform: rotate(108deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick19 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(114deg);
          transform: rotate(114deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick20 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick21 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
          transform: rotate(126deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick22 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(132deg);
          transform: rotate(132deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick23 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(138deg);
          transform: rotate(138deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick24 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
          transform: rotate(144deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick25 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
          transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick26 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(156deg);
          transform: rotate(156deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick27 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
          transform: rotate(162deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick28 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(168deg);
          transform: rotate(168deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick29 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(174deg);
          transform: rotate(174deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick30 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick31 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(186deg);
          transform: rotate(186deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick32 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(192deg);
          transform: rotate(192deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick33 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(198deg);
          transform: rotate(198deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick34 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(204deg);
          transform: rotate(204deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick35 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
          transform: rotate(210deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick36 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg);
          transform: rotate(216deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick37 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(222deg);
          transform: rotate(222deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick38 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(228deg);
          transform: rotate(228deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick39 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(234deg);
          transform: rotate(234deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick40 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
          transform: rotate(240deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick41 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(246deg);
          transform: rotate(246deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick42 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(252deg);
          transform: rotate(252deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick43 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(258deg);
          transform: rotate(258deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick44 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(264deg);
          transform: rotate(264deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick45 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
          transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick46 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(276deg);
          transform: rotate(276deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick47 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(282deg);
          transform: rotate(282deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick48 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg);
          transform: rotate(288deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick49 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(294deg);
          transform: rotate(294deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick50 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
          transform: rotate(300deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick51 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(306deg);
          transform: rotate(306deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick52 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(312deg);
          transform: rotate(312deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick53 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(318deg);
          transform: rotate(318deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick54 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(324deg);
          transform: rotate(324deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick55 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
          transform: rotate(330deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick56 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(336deg);
          transform: rotate(336deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick57 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(342deg);
          transform: rotate(342deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick58 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(348deg);
          transform: rotate(348deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick59 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(354deg);
          transform: rotate(354deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#tick60 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pomodoro-container">
 <div id="pomodoro">
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick1">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick2">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick3">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick4">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick5">
   <div class="mark-face">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick6">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick7">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick8">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick9">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick10">
   <div class="mark-face">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick11">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick12">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick13">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick14">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick15">
   <div class="mark-face">15</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick16">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick17">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick18">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick19">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick20">
   <div class="mark-face">20</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick21">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick22">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick23">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick24">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick25">
   <div class="mark-face">25</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick26">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick27">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick28">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick29">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick30">
   <div class="mark-face">30</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick31">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick32">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick33">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick34">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick35">
   <div class="mark-face">35</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick36">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick37">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick38">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick39">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick40">
   <div class="mark-face">40</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick41">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick42">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick43">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick44">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick45">
   <div class="mark-face">45</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick46">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick47">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick48">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick49">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick50">
   <div class="mark-face">50</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick51">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick52">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick53">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick54">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick55">
   <div class="mark-face">55</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick56">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick57">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick58">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick59">
   <div class="mark-face">|</div>
  </div>
  <div class="time-mark" id="tick60">
   <div class="mark-face">60</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For your convenience, you can find a CodePen of the above code-snippet [here](https://codepen.io/dankest_of_memes/pen/qjzgXQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I'm not 3D expert I can say what I see here. You have problem in alignment of your circles. Origin of red circle and origin of marks-circle aren't at the same place. Actually both, X and Y alignment are wrong so `time-mark` class needs some minor modifications.

Fix X alignment like this (not perfect solution).

```
left: calc(50% - 9.6px);
```

Fix Y alignment like this

```
top: calc(50% - 266px);
```

Major problem here was **vh** units which is percent of viewport height, not height of your container. Change it to percents and you fix `top` property (Y) alignment. I don't understand how you calculate `left` but it also needs adjustments.

Anyway, to get visual aid in alignment just change angle of view from 85 to e.g. 25, set some background color to marks and disable (comment) `backface-visibility` property of `mark-face` class.

Left side of image below shows possible result of your code. On the right side you can see what you get after applying changes I mentioned.

[image]

This is not perfect, but very close to perfect. Course, if I got right what you want in the first place.

Point is to get origins of both circles in the same place. Otherwise, object rotates around a point which is halfway between centers of two circles and that's why rotation looks distorted.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your alignment :

[image]

That's why on rotation it seems like its off the center point but its not. Your divs are not properly aligned to each other.

try changing

```
top: calc(50vh - 266px);
```

to

```
top: calc(50% - 266px);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxGYbj